# how to send a file thru bluetooth to a smartphone that already has a earphone connected?

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, transfer

how to send a file thru bluetooth to a smartphone that already has a earphone connected?

My smartphone, Samsung J7, already has a bluetooth earphone connected.
If there was nothing connected, I could just click on connect in ubuntu and transfer the file.
Is the only option to disconnect the earphones?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to be precise and fast:

- Go to a file manager and Ctrl+C on the single file you want to send (if there are more than one files, just zip them all together first).
- On Bluetooth settings: click on your device to open the connect window, but do NOT connect yet.
- On connect window: click on 'send files...'
- On file selection window: make it "on top" and place it's select button near the connect button of the previous window.
- On file selection window: press Ctrl+L and paste the file (full path name) you just copied.
- On connect window: be careful now, click on the Connect button and wait for it to connect. It will be connected for a very short time, so you need to be fast!
- File selection window: click 2 times on the select button (the 1st time will select the window, the 2nd time will activate the button), and be patient for 30 seconds while it tries to begin sending the file.